# What are the advantages of having Hibernate NamingStrategy

Tags: hibernate, persistence

What are the advantages of having Hibernate `NamingStrategy` inside persistence class ?

In Hibernate 3.6 has four implementations of `org.hibernate.cfg.NamingStrategy` interface:

```
org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy
org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy
org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
```

and how its difference between each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the point of a `NamingStrategy` is to be an advantage. I remember only two times using it. Once was because of a defined rule of naming conventions from the institution that my company was writing software for.

They had a convention that many to many relationships must have a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) with the name of the other tables and `"_x_"`. Something like `users_x_roles`.

And with Informix I had a problem because the `DefaultNamingStrategy` generated invalid DDL.